# Users see blank space instead of AdSense Ads

Tags: google-adsense

I observed that ads from Google Adsense are getting displayed properly
My many of the friends are not able to see them, they see a blank space instead.

Moreover, I observed that google is showing fewer clicks than actual. I agree that I shouldn't get paid for fake clicks, but I'm confused about the number of actual clicks.

Comment: 1 of my friend reported that ads are visible only on widows 7 but not on windows xp. many times they appeared after refreshing page 3-4 times

Comment: i am permanently blocked via google adsense. I also had lost my money i earned. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem myself on one of my websites. It's a weblog with pictures running about 200 visitors a day, so not very big/popular. On the individual post pages ads usually show, but on the main page (overview of the last 10 posts) banners are often individual. I think it's because there's just not enough relevant content for Google to match an ad to. Maybe you could try adding more (relevant) content to the pages and see if it catches on?

Concerning the clicks, I have no idea, but what exactly confuses you? I'm afraid there's not a lot of people that click Google ads anymore...

Comment: i clicked myself from 6 different locations,cities, countries without using any proxy. still it shows very less clicks

Comment: It is against TOS to click your own ads.

Answer (score 2):

A blank space may appear if ads are blocked by some browser extension, through the HOSTS file, at the network level or one of these [other mechanisms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/selectively-filtering-content-in-web-browsers).

Comment: 20-30% time it is hidden to myself. while rest time it appears properly